# Passing values from the web service to the bar-chart in android

Tags: android, bar-chart

I am trying to pass two values ie.,a & b values,to the x-axis and y-axis for creating a bar chart in android.But i am getting the a and b values from the web service by consuming it.Here i use SOAP method for consuming the web service.

After trying of some code.i got these things on my log-cat.Can anyone let me know how to solve these issues? suggestions please..

**LOGCAT**

```
10-03 11:35:25.285: W/KeyCharacterMap(404): No keyboard for id 0
10-03 11:35:25.295: W/KeyCharacterMap(404): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-03 11:35:38.195: D/AndroidRuntime(404): Shutting down VM
10-03 11:35:38.195: W/dalvikvm(404): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test_wb/com.example.test_wb.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:263)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:287)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.example.test_wb.ResultActivity.<init>(ResultActivity.java:25)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
10-03 11:35:38.205: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  ... 11 more
```

**Main_WB.java**

```
public class Main_WB extends Activity
{
EditText edt1, edt2;
// TextView txt_1;

Button btn;
ArrayList<String> result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

result = new ArrayList<String>();

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        result.addAll(getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(), edt2.getText().toString()));

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);

        in.putExtra("gotonextpageX", result.get(0));
        in.putExtra("gotonextpageY", result.get(1));

        startActivity(in);
    }
});
}
private ArrayList<String> getTMSChart(String FromDate, String ToDate) 
{
// txt_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet = true;

String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";
String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
request.addProperty("FromDate", FromDate);
request.addProperty("ToDate", ToDate);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

String x = "", y = "";

ArrayList<String> stringResult = new ArrayList<String>();

try 
{
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    SoapObject root = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) (result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
    int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++) 
    {
        SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
        int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++) 
        {

            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No").toString());
            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate").toString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
}

return stringResult; 
} 
}
```

**ResultActivity.java**

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity 
{   
TextView txt1,txt2;

String a,b;

double x_axis = Double.parseDouble(a); // Type casting
double y_axis = Double.parseDouble(b); // Type casting

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main1);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null)
{   
    a = extras.getString("gotonextpageX");
    b = extras.getString("gotonextpageY");
  }
else
{
}
draw();

//txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVw);
//txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVw2);
//txt1.setText(x);
//txt2.setText(y);

}

public void draw()
{   

String[] titles = new String[] { "Order's profit of the year", " " };

List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

values.add(new double[] { y_axis });

int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

 setChartSettings(renderer, "Profit for the year 2012", " ", " ",0,x_axis, 0,y_axis, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

renderer.setXLabels(1);
renderer.addXTextLabel(100, "x");

//renderer.addXTextLabel(200, "ord2");
//renderer.addXTextLabel(300, "ord3");
//renderer.addXTextLabel(400, "ord4");
//renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);

int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
    seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    }

ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
{   

  // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

    int length = colors.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(colors[i]);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
    return renderer;
    }

 protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
String yTitle, double xMin, double x_axis2, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
{   

// sets lots of default values for this renderer

renderer.setChartTitle(title);
renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);

//renderer.setXAxisMax(x2);

renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
{   
// adds the axis titles and values into the data-set

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
int length = titles.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);

    double[] v = values.get(i);
    int seriesLength = v.length;

    for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
    {
        series.add(v[k]);
    }

    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
}
return dataset;
 }    }
```

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `String a,b;` contains?

It will surely throw `NPE`, since you are

```
double x_axis = Double.parseDouble(a); // Type casting
double y_axis = Double.parseDouble(b); // Type casting
```

Give some value to a,b then parse it.

In your case: Write

```
double x_axis = Double.parseDouble(a); // Type casting
double y_axis = Double.parseDouble(b); // Type casting
```

in the `if(extras!=null){}`

**EDIT:**

```
if(extras != null)
{   
    a = extras.getString("gotonextpageX");
    b = extras.getString("gotonextpageY");
    double x_axis = Double.parseDouble(a); // Type casting
    double y_axis = Double.parseDouble(b); // Type casting
  }
```

Comment: Both a and b are collecting the values from the web service,so i am trying to assign that values to the x and y axis of a barchart for creating a barchart

Comment: Was my way of passing the values for creating bar-chart is wrong?

Comment: yes, but check where you are parsing a & b variables to float, you are doing it before getting the a & b values. Check my answer. I have edited it.

Comment: Your parsing logic is not wrong, the place where you are parsing is wrong.

Comment: If i follow your suggestion,in my source,61st and 68th line is showing error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17479/discussion-between-prabu-and-shrikant)